# Qt + VTK + Cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, vtk

I'm running OSX 10.6 (Snow Leopard), Qt 4.6, VTK 5.4, and Cmake 2.8. I installed Qt, then VTK and Cmake. I configured VTK to use QT 4.6 (turned on VTK_USE_GUISUPPORT and VTK_USE_QVTK). The configuration and installation worked painlessly but if I run Cmake with Qt references the compilation fails during the subsequent make process because of failed dependency resolution.

As an example, I tried to build the Qt ImageViewer example (VTK/Examples/GUI/Qt/ImageViewer) and it failed to find qapplication.h (and all other qt headers). Any ideas about why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like CMake isn't finding Qt. Please paste your compilation and CMake output somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

CMake finds Qt by looking for `qmake` (ironic, eh?). Make sure `qmake` is in your path.

Also, make sure VTK and Qt 4.6 were compiled with the same version of gcc/g++. Weird runtime errors (like cout not working) can result.

Comment: Ironic indeed, it should know how to generate the `moc` and `ui` and other Qt steps IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

First you should set `DESIRED_QT_VERSION` to 4. When it's ready, you could chose `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE` to your qmake binary.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the CMakeCache.txt in your build folder for cmake tends to have all the necessary diagnostics info for stuff like this. Almost certainly there's a string field for the include path that is blank right now due to not being found.